# Algorithm Comparison with O-notation

Tags: algorithm, runtime, time-complexity

We consider two algorithms, Algo1 and Algo2, that solve the same
problem.  For any input of size *n*, Algo1 takes time `T_1(n)` and
Algo2 takes time `T_2(n)`.

Suppose that `T_1(n)` completes in `O(n^2)` and `T_2(n)` in `O(n^3)`. 
Does it imply that there exists *n0* such that for `n > n0*`, Algo1 runs faster than Algo2 on inputs of size `n`?

Sorry, I am very new to this subject, and I am not sure how to start to even approach this problem. Any hints towards the right direction would be extremelt appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: The answer is no. Algorithm 2 could run in constant time while Algorithm 1 might require at least `n^2` operations. `T_2(n)` being in `O(n^3)` does not mean that `T_2(n)` isn't also in `O(1)`.

Comment: Hello, I am wondering if there is such counter example for this case ?

Comment: I posted a counterexample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a counterexample, here are two algorithms for calculating the square of an integer in JavaScript.

Algorithm1:

```js
console.log( Algorithm1( 5 ) ); // 25

function Algorithm1 ( n ) {
  let count = 0;
  for ( let i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    for ( let j = 0; j < n; j++ )
      count++;
  return count;
}
```

Algorithm2:

```js
console.log( Algorithm2( 5 ) ); // 25

function Algorithm2 ( n ) {
  return n*n;
}
```

Algorithm1 is in `Ө(n²)` and therefore not in `O(1)`.

Algorithm2 is in `O(1)` and therefore trivially also in `O(n³)`.

Thus there is no `n0` such that for `n > n0` Algorithm1 is faster than Algorithm2.

Comment: I understand. I should have understood that O(1) is still in O(n^3). Thank you so much! @Paulpro